# Inexplicable page refreshes getting triggered after a socket.io message

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm writing a multiroom chat server to learn nodejs.

The code is here: https://github.com/DanielHeath/furious-earth-2/tree/backbone
And the app is live here: http://furious-earth.herokuapp.com/

The issue is that when running in development mode, the page refreshes whenever you log in to a room.

What I've found so far:

- This doesn't happen in production
- Anything you write to the console is lost when the page reloads
- The chrome debugger crashes the tab if you use it with socket.io code
- The firefox debugger doesn't stop the page from reloading
- The url is getting a '?' parameter appended

I can't figure out what is causing it - or even how to approach debugging it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd excerpt the portions of the code that you suspect to have something to do with the issue; probably something about the client-side code that triggers socket.io operations. A common cause of unexpected page refreshes is that event handlers on elements that cause a page refresh naturally (`<a>` tags of form submit elements) don't properly prevent the default action

Comment: Thank you - it was the form submit that was doing it. Want to resubmit your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: OK will do - glad I guessed right :-)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to look for: event handlers on your page(s) bound to `<a>` elements or to things that cause form submission (`<button>` tags with type "submit", or "submit" `<input>` elements, and other things like that).  If those don't properly prevent the default action of "click" events, then the browser will end up reloading the page(s).